# Where does Android Studio store the signed APKs?

Tags: android, android-studio

I just built a signed APK of my app, but I cannot find it anywhere. The directory `project/app/build/outputs/apk/` only give me the debug version, not the release signed one.

And, when clicking "Locate" after the build, it opens `project/app/release`, which also does not hold my signed APK.

Where can I find my signed APK?

I am using Android Studio 3.2.1.

Comment: When going through the signing wizard you can specify the location, there you will find the default path, or just change it to set one that better suits you. It is exactly in the final window where the finish button, at the very top you will see "Destination Folder"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you build your signed APK? 
The location you mentioned is default location and only used when using "Build APK" option:

[image: this option]]

If you use "Generate Signed Bundle" option, you can specify the APK location:

[image: enter image description here]]

Answer (score -2):

It will be here

C:\Users....\AndroidStudioProjects\YourProject\app\release

Comment: I specifically said that it is not there.